# Keyboard layout with Solaris in VirtualBox

Tags: solaris, keyboard-layout

Today I've installed Solaris 11.2 on Oracle VM VirtualBox. After that when I type the `|` symbol at the command prompt, it's wrongly displaying a `~` symbol. Could someone help me any fix / correction this query.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the keyboard layout and model using the GUI.  Your problem also might be due to incorrect locale settings (even `en_GB` and `en_US` are not really the same on the keyboard).  If the GUI is not accessible, you might be able to `ssh` into the machine and repair these settings.

Further reading:

- [Setting Keyboard Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24676/glqko.html) (GUI)
- [Internationalization and Localization Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/glmwl.html)
- [How to change the Keyboard layout on Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443605/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-on-solaris) (command-line)